# What is the difference between ICAO and non-ICAO flight address?

Tags: ads-b, icao

In [document 260B](http://www.anteni.net/adsb/Doc/1090-WP30-18-DRAFT_DO-260B-V42.pdf), "Minimum operational performance standards for 1090Mhz Extended Squitter", on page 47 of the pdf, in the DF18 format they have mentioned for a particular CF(code format), "non-ICAO flight address".

So I wanted to know what the difference was between ICAO and non-ICAO flight address?

Comment: Hello @vinas sunder, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6):

The use of the non-ICAO flight address field is described in the very same document, on table 2-11, page 53 of the PDF:

> AA field holds another kind of address for the transmitting
>   ADS-B Participant: a self-assigned "anonymous" address, a
>   ground vehicle address, or a surface obstruction address.

Ground vehicles and surface or tethered obstructions want to participate in ADS-B, but they don't have ICAO aircraft addresses, so they have to have their own addresses. Since these addresses aren't centrally assigned, the CF field is used to keep them distinct: otherwise, you could have a vehicle address that conflicts with an ICAO aircraft address.

The different kinds of addresses are further described in section 2.2.5.1.1 (p 172 of the PDF).